# How do I check to see if two expressions are equal?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

This is what I am trying:

```
(2 x - 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - v)/(2 x + 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - v) == (Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[x - v])^4/v^2
```

but it's not working. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 5):

It's not resolving because it depends on the values of x and v as to whether it is true or not:

```
ArrayPlot@ Boole@Table[(2 x - 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - v)/(2 x + 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - v) ==
 (Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[x - v])^4/v^2, {x, -5, 5, 0.03}, {v, -5, 5, 0.03}]
```

[image: truths]

If you could simplify it with a condition, say $x>v$:

```
Simplify[(2 x - 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - v)/(2 x + 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - v) ==
  (Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[x - v])^4/v^2, x > v]
```

> `True`

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Correction to broader solution set

The conditions for the equality to hold for reals are given by

```
Reduce[(2 x - 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - v)/(2 x + 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - 
     v) == (Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[x - v])^4/v^2, {x, v}, Reals]
```

> x >= 0 && (v < 0 || 0 < v <= x)

However,

```
Reduce[{(2 x - 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - v)/(2 x + 2 Sqrt[x (x - v)] - 
      v) == (Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[x - v])^4/v^2, 
  Element[{x, v}, Reals]}, {x, v}, Complexes]
```

> (x < 0 && (v == 2 x || v == x)) || (x > 
>       0 && (v == 2 x || v < 0 || 0 < v < x || v >= x)) || (x <= 0 &&     v < x) || (x == 0 && v > 0)

This produces a broader solution set because "If dom is Reals, or a subset such as Integers or Rationals, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be real" whereas "Reduce[expr&&vars [Element] Reals, vars, Complexes] performs reductions with variables assumed real, but function values allowed to be complex."